# how can I include a javascipt code in angular 2+?

Tags: javascript, angular

This is the HTML code:

```
<div id="myNav" class="overlay">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
        <div class="overlay-content">
          <a href="#">About</a>`enter code here`
          <a href="#">Services</a>
          <a href="#">Clients</a>
          <a href="#">Contact</a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <h2>Fullscreen Overlay Nav Example</h2>
      <p>Click on the element below to open the fullscreen overlay navigation menu.</p>
      <p>In this example, the navigation menu will slide in, from left to right:</p>
      <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; open</span>
```

where should I include this script tag in angular project for it to work?

```
<script>
    function openNav() {
      document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "100%";
    }

    function closeNav() {
      document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "0%";
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Accessing the DOM directly isn't a good idea in Angular. You could, in theory, access DOM using methods like `document.getElementById()` or `document.querySelector()` in the component controller. But don't do it.

There are numerous other better ways to manipulate the DOM from the controller. One simple and quick way in your case would be to use `[style.width.%]` attribute property binding. Try the following

component.html

```html
<div [style.width.%]="customWidth" id="myNav" class="overlay">
```

And in the controller you could do the following

component.ts

```js
export class SampleComponent implements OnInit {
  customWidth = 100;   // <-- default width percentage

  public openNav() {
    this.customWidth = 100;
  }

  public closeNav() {
    this.customWidth = 0;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

There are many more refined controls provided by Angular to modify the DOM. For eg, you could use many other CSS units like `[style.width.px]`, `[style.width.em]`, `[style.width.in]` and so on. You could apply multiple styles using [`ngStyle`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle). For more advanced DOM features, look into Angular [Renderer2](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2).

Comment: where should i put that div tag? can u plz give me the exact code?

Comment: I only added the expression `[style.width.%]="customWidth"` to the `div` that was already present in your question. I didn't introduce any new statements to your HTML template. If you're new to Angular, I'd recommend you to go through this tutorial: https://angular.io/tutorial. It introduces some of the basics.

Comment: i've tried using this. But the onlick function isn't working. the navbar is getting displayed permanently now. and when I click on cross it doesn't close down.

Comment: I'd say that is different issue. You might need to look into the animation triggered by the CSS.